# HtmlUnit: Login to ESSE3 platform

Tags: java, html, authentication, htmlunit, jsessionid

I'm trying to login using HtmlUnit to the following website that uses ESSE3 (Student Management System): https://www.studenti.ict.uniba.it/esse3/Home.do

This is the href value of 'Login': auth/Logon.do;jsessionid=EF0F5942A7390DB3A5C5AD99955D4C3E.jvm2b

Then, the complete authentication link would be: https://www.studenti.ict.uniba.it/esse3/auth/Logon.do;jsessionid=EF0F5942A7390DB3A5C5AD99955D4C3E.jvm2b

But I have no clue on how I can fill the username and password fields because there are no form or input fields in the html.

Answer (score 0):

There are some points:

1. To fill the username and password, you should use `CredentialsProvider`, e.g.

   ```
   try (final WebClient webClient = new WebClient()) {
       DefaultCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = 
               (DefaultCredentialsProvider) webClient.getCredentialsProvider();
       credentialsProvider.addCredentials("someuser", "somepass");
       HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("https://www.studenti.ict.uniba.it/esse3/Home.do");
       HtmlPage page2 = page.getAnchorByText("Login").click();
   }
   ```

2. <strike>There is `illegal character` in the java script, which can be overcome by the below as hinted [here](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/faq.html#HowToModifyRequestOrResponse), this could be a bug in HtmlUnit, to be investigated:</strike>

   ```
           public WebResponse getResponse(WebRequest request) throws IOException {
               WebResponse response = super.getResponse(request);
               if (request.getUrl().toExternalForm().contains("footable/js")) {
                   String content = response.getContentAsString();

                   StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                   for (int i = 0; i < content.length(); i++) {
                       char ch = content.charAt(i);
                       if (ch >= 7 && ch <= 127) {
                           builder.append(content.charAt(i));
                       }
                   }
                   content = builder.toString();

                   WebResponseData data = new WebResponseData(content.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8),
                           response.getStatusCode(), response.getStatusMessage(), response.getResponseHeaders());
                   response = new WebResponse(data, request, response.getLoadTime());
               }
               return response;
           }
       };
   ```

   **Update :** this is now fixed in SVN.

3. <strike>It complains about CSSRuleList:</strike>

   ```
   TypeError: Cannot find function item in object [object CSSRuleList]
   ```

   which could be fixed by using `BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_45`, to be investigated if it should be supported in Chrome/IE.

   **Update :** this is now fixed in SVN.

4. Still it complains about:

   ```
   TypeError: Cannot read property "selectorText" from null
   ```

   which should be [isolated as minimal case](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/submittingJSBugs.html).